# Combining Separate Elements in Two Separate Lists with a Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This program is utilized with the intended function to

1. Create a list using user input to generate five names,
2. Create a list using user input to generate five marks/grades in numeric form.
3. Create a third list that combine each element in the
       first list with the corresponding indexed place in the second list.

For example:

```
Student_Names= []
Marks= []
StudentNames_Marks= []
for i in range (5): #Go through and append the student names into Student_Names list by requesting the information five times and appending each time
    _name= input("Please enter a name for the student records list. ")
    Student_Names.append(_name)
_sum=0 #This is used to create a second for loop under the event that they do not enter a digit within the first list, allowing them to continue forward
for i in range (5):
    _marks= input("Please enter marks in digit format. ")
    if _marks.isalpha():
        print("Please enter a digit, such as 10 instead of ten.")
        _sum=_sum+1 #Add one to the sum to create the amount of loops in the second for loop
    else:
        Marks.append(_marks)
if _sum>0:
    for i in range(_sum):
        _marks=input("Please enter marks in digit format. ")
        if _marks.isalpha():
            print("Please enter a digit, such as 10 instead of ten. The program will not run properly. Please restart the program.")
        else:
            Marks.append(_marks)
_numbera= len(Student_Names) #Using the lengths of the list to determine the length of the for loop
_numberb= len(Marks)
_length= _numbera+_numberb
for i in range (5):
    _value=Student_Names.pop()
    StudentNames_Marks.append(_value)
    _value=Marks.pop()
    StudentNames_Marks.append(_value)

print(StudentNames_Marks)
```

Which would then produce the following on the console if the following were entered in the prompts:

> Name prompt responses: James, Jack, Ivy, Eva, Lee Marks: 10, 64, 36,
>   86, 35 Student_Names= ['James', 'Jack', 'Ivy', 'Eva', 'Lee'] Marks=
>   ['10', '64', '36', '86', '35'] StudentNames_Marks= ['Lee', '35',
>   'Eva', '86', 'Ivy', '36', 'Jack', '64', 'James', '10'

However, I am stuck at developing the final step. I have currently gotten a list that takes the elements from the first two lists in the proper order, as indicated above. I'm not sure how to combine the elements in the final list utilzing a dash so it'd look more like this:

> StudentNames_Marks= ['Lee- 35', 'Eva- 86', 'Ivy- 36', 'Jack- 64',
>   'James- 10']

How do I go about doing something like that?

Comment: Not related to your question, but please don't prefix all those variables with `_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner using `zip` and `list comprehension`:

```
>>> ['-'.join(ele) for ele in zip(student_names, marks)]
```

Here, the `zip` command is used to create tuples combining the `student_name` and `marks` which are then joined together using `join` function.

#driver values :

```
IN : student_names= ['James', 'Jack', 'Ivy', 'Eva', 'Lee']
IN : marks = ['10', '64', '36', '86', '35']
OUT : ['James-10', 'Jack-64', 'Ivy-36', 'Eva-86', 'Lee-35']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative way** (using one list only):

You can use `zip` to take two items from one list at a time and add a `-` in between them.

```
StudentNames_Marks= ['Lee', '35', 'Eva', '86', 'Ivy', '36', 'Jack', '64', 'James', '10']

def group(iterable, n):
   return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

StudentNames_Marks_new = []
for x, y in group(StudentNames_Marks, 2):
    StudentNames_Marks_new.append('{}-{}'.format(x, y))

print(StudentNames_Marks_new)

# ['Lee-35', 'Eva-86', 'Ivy-36', 'Jack-64', 'James-10']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
student_names= ['James', 'Jack', 'Ivy', 'Eva', 'Lee']
marks = ['10', '64', '36', '86', '35']

result = ["{}-{}".format(name, mark) for name, mark in zip(student_names, marks)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert your final output into desired you can use:

```
StudentNames_Marks = ['Lee', '35', 'Eva', '86', 'Ivy', '36', 'Jack', '64', 'James', '10']
StudentNames_Marks = ['-'.join(nm) for nm in zip(StudentNames_Marks[::2],StudentNames_Marks[1::2]]
StudentNames_Marks
#['Lee- 35', 'Eva- 86', 'Ivy- 36', 'Jack- 64', 'James- 10']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power of comprehensions:

```
# combine every name with the corresponding mark
def combine(names, marks):
    if len(names) != len(marks):
        # throw an exception or return some error value
        pass
    else:
        return [name + '-' + mark for name, mark in zip(names, marks)]
```